# Mini Macro in SAS to change date format?

Tags: sas

I have a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD in a number of places in code and I want to change it using %let to a SAS System Automatic date format. The issue is that the code is to be run daily and the date will need to change to currentdate. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%let currdate = %sysfunc(today(), yymmdd10.);
```